# form is not activated in Rasa 2.0

Tags: rasa-nlu, rasa, rasa-core

I'm trying to integrate a form in my rasa chatbot.
In domain.yml, I have included the following:

1. I declared the slots:

```
slots:
    question1:
      type: text
   question2:
     type: text
   question3:
     type: text
```

2. the questions that the form is supposed to send to the user:

```
     utter_ask_question1: 
       - text:" first question goes here"
     utter_ask_question2: 
       - text:" second question goes here"
     utter_ask_question3: 
       - text:" third question goes here"
```

3. defined the form as:

```
forms: 
    user_quiz_form:
    question1:
      - type: from_text
        # entity: date
    question2:
       - type: from_text
    question3:
       - type: from_text
```

4. the actions section also contains :

```
   actions:
      - action_submit
      - user_quiz_form
```

The file rules.yml contains:

```
   - rule: Activate quiz form
       steps:
       - intent: quiz
       - action: utter_quiz
       - action: user_quiz_form
       - active_loop: user_quiz_form
   - rule: Submit quiz form
     condition:
     - active_loop: user_quiz_form
    steps:
     - action: user_quiz_form
    - active_loop: null
    - slot_was_set:
      - requested_slot: null
    - action: action_submit
```

and actions.py is:

```
from typing import Any, Text, Dict, List
from rasa_sdk import Action, Tracker
from rasa_sdk.events import SlotSet, EventType
from rasa_sdk.executor import CollectingDispatcher
import webbrowser

class ValidateForm(Action):
    def name(self) -> Text:
        return "user_quiz_form"

    def run(
        self, dispatcher: CollectingDispatcher, tracker: Tracker, domain: Dict
    ) -> List[EventType]:
         required_slots = ["question1","question2", "question3"]
        
        for slot_name in required_slots:
          if tracker.slots.get(slot_name) is None:
                # The slot is not filled yet. Request the user to fill this slot next.
             return [SlotSet("requested_slot", slot_name)]
        return [SlotSet("requested_slot", None)]

class ActionSubmit(Action):
    def name(self) -> Text:
        return "action_submit"
    def run(
        self,
        dispatcher,
        tracker: Tracker,
        domain: "DomainDict",
    ) -> List[Dict[Text, Any]]:
       print("****************SUBMIT*****************")
       dispatcher.utter_message(template="utter_quiz_thanks", date=tracker.slots.get("question1"))
       return []
```

When the form is triggered, it doesn't' ask the questions to the user and returns utter_quiz_thanks with None as question1 value.

Answer (score 0):

Is this the same indentation you're using in your domain.yml? If so, you're missing some indents; the slots underneath the form need to be indented (see below for an example). My guess is that you're launching the form correctly, but due to the indent issues your assistant is treating it as a form with 0 questions.

```
forms:
  restaurant_form:
    cuisine:
      - type: from_entity
        entity: cuisine
    num_people:
      - type: from_entity
        entity: number
```

Comment: I'm using the correct indentation in my domain.yml, exactly like in your example.

Comment: Hm, noted. Would you mind sharing your full logs for the conversation? (`rasa shell -vv`)

Edit to add: My go to quick fix at the moment is deleting the most recent model & retraining in case you want to try that as well.